# Adding a increasing value

Tags: batch-file

I know this one is an easy one, but it's driving me nuts

Need help with setting up a counter to increase by 1

I have a txt file with a `100x timestamp` and when I enter `1000` all I get is `1001`
and I'm trying to get `1001,1002,1003`

Here is the script I am using

```
@ECHO Off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

@For %%G In ("%~dp0New Folder1") Do Set "sourcedir=%%~fG"
@For %%G In ("%~dp0New Folder2") Do Set "destdir=%%~fG"

Set /p Stamp=Enter TimeStamp:
SET /a TimeCount=%Stamp%
SET /a TimeCount+=1

FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt"') DO (
(
 for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%b in ('findstr /N "^" "%sourcedir%\%%q"') do (
   set "line=%%c"
   if defined line (
    IF "%%c" equ "!line:timestamp=!" (ECHO %%c) ELSE (
       for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%v in ("%%c") do ECHO %%v: %TimeCount%,
    )
   ) ELSE ECHO(
  )
)>"%destdir%\%%q"
```

Thanks guys

Comment: `ECHO %%v: !TimeCount!,` (since `timecount` is being varied, I presume) - but it will appear to do nothing since `timecount` is being varied outside the loop, but not within it (presumably you need to increment it within the `%%q` loop, before the `%%b` loop, so just before the `for...%%b`)

Comment: yes, of course ...silly me I knew about the `for---%%b` that was my original testing. but was no using the `! !` so I thought I had it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Magoo for pointing out `!Timecount!`

Here is the correct way to set up the script to increase by 1

This script will add to your number if you enter 100 and you have 10 repeated codes within the same file you will get `101,102,103,...110, etc...` 
Now the adding will carry over to all other files so.. 
If you have 2 files in the same folder and each have 10 repeated codes each the script will count from `101` to `120`

```
@ECHO Off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

@For %%G In ("%~dp0New Folder1") Do Set "sourcedir=%%~fG"
@For %%G In ("%~dp0New Folder2") Do Set "destdir=%%~fG"

Set /p Stamp=Enter TimeStamp:
SET /a TimeCount=%Stamp%

FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt"') DO (
(
 for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%b in ('findstr /N "^" "%sourcedir%\%%q"') do (
   set "line=%%c"
   if defined line (
    IF "%%c" equ "!line:timestamp=!" (ECHO %%c) ELSE (
    SET /a TimeCount+=1
       for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%v in ("%%c") do ECHO %%v: !TimeCount!,
    )
   ) ELSE ECHO(
  )
)>"%destdir%\%%q"
)
```

Now by moving this  `SET /a TimeCount=%Stamp%` under the `For Loop` 
you will 2 results each file will get `101` to `110`

```
@ECHO Off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

@For %%G In ("%~dp0New Folder1") Do Set "sourcedir=%%~fG"
@For %%G In ("%~dp0New Folder2") Do Set "destdir=%%~fG"

Set /p Stamp=Enter TimeStamp:

FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt"') DO (
SET /a TimeCount=%Stamp%
(
 for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%b in ('findstr /N "^" "%sourcedir%\%%q"') do (
   set "line=%%c"
   if defined line (
    IF "%%c" equ "!line:timestamp=!" (ECHO %%c) ELSE (
    SET /a TimeCount+=1
       for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%v in ("%%c") do ECHO %%v: !TimeCount!,
    )
   ) ELSE ECHO(
  )
)>"%destdir%\%%q"
)
```